# How to define Spacing from top margin

Tags: pdftex, margins, overleaf

I have to follow these writing rules.

[image]

I can set the top margin to 3 cm. for the first sentence. But the others I don't know.

So, my question is how to measure the exact space from the top margin to meet the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following provides what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[top=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup
  \centering
  UNIVERSITY

  \vspace{\dimexpr3.5cm-\baselineskip}

  INSTITUTION

  \vspace{\dimexpr3.5cm-\baselineskip}

  TITLE

  \vspace{\dimexpr4cm-\baselineskip}

  NAME
  \par
\endgroup

\clearpage

Rest of your document \ldots

\end{document}
```

The use of `\dimexpr<len>-\baselineskip` in measuring the `v`ertical `space` between title elements ensures that you don't include consideration for the line of text being printed.

[image]

The above vertical rules highlighting the lengths were printed using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic). Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[top=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \hspace{.4\paperwidth}\rule[-3cm]{1pt}{3cm}%
  }%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \hspace{\dimexpr.4\paperwidth+1em}\raisebox{-3cm}{3cm}%
  }%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \hspace{\dimexpr.4\paperwidth-1em}\raisebox{-3cm}{\rule[-3.5cm]{1pt}{3.5cm}}%
  }%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \hspace{.4\paperwidth}\raisebox{-6.5cm}{3.5cm}%
  }%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \hspace{\dimexpr.4\paperwidth-2em}{\raisebox{-3cm}{\rule[-7cm]{1pt}{7cm}}}%
  }%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \hspace{\dimexpr.4\paperwidth-1em}{\raisebox{-10cm}{7cm}}%
  }%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \hspace{\dimexpr.4\paperwidth-3em}{\raisebox{-3cm}{\rule[-11cm]{1pt}{11cm}}}%
  }%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \hspace{\dimexpr.4\paperwidth-2em}{\raisebox{-14cm}{11cm}}%
  }%
}%

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup
  \centering
  UNIVERSITY

  \vspace{\dimexpr3.5cm-\baselineskip}

  INSTITUTION

  \vspace{\dimexpr3.5cm-\baselineskip}

  TITLE

  \vspace{\dimexpr4cm-\baselineskip}

  NAME
  \par
\endgroup

\clearpage

Rest of your document \ldots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helps me. At first, it gives me an extra line. Then I realized that because I set \setlength{\parskip}{12pt}. So I set \parskip to 0 and it perfectly works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what You wanted?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=0cm,right=0cm, top=3cm,bottom=0cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

  \begin{titlepage}

  \begin{center}
  UNIVERSITY
  \end{center}
  \vspace{3.5 cm}

  \begin{center}
  INSTITUTION
  \end{center}
  \vspace{3.5 cm}


  \begin{center}
  TITLE
  \end{center}
  \vspace{4 cm}

  \begin{center}
  NAME
  \end{center}
  \end{titlepage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The center environment adds space above and below the text, plus the text itself.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for multiple lines of text and varying font sizes.  It works by placing the text inside boxes of a specified height + depth.  Each `\parbox` is treated as one line of a paragraph.  `\lineskip` is added between boxes since the depth exceeds `\baselineskip`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[top=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup
\lineskip=0pt
\noindent\parbox[t][3.5cm][t]{\textwidth}{\centering
  UNIVERSITY}
\parbox[t][3.5cm][t]{\textwidth}{\centering
  INSTITUTION}
\parbox[t][4cm][t]{\textwidth}{\centering
  TITLE}
\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\centering
  NAME}
\endgroup

\newpage

Rest of your document \ldots

\end{document}
```